# How to change default notification permission for my Android app?

Tags: android, permissions, android-permissions

For some reason the Notifications are blocked by default on for my Android app. I've set the permission on my AndroidManifest.xml file, but it still blocked by default - how do I enable it by default?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Fait"
    tools:targetApi="31">
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting in Android 13, you must ask the user for notification permissions. Notifications are automatically blocked until you explicitly request permission from the user and the user allows them. See [Notification runtime permission](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission).